# OnTabChanged method in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, xcode4.2

I'm quite new to iOS/Objective-C Developing and I'm writing my first serious iPhone/iPad App. The App that I am building is Tab-Based. There's a Settings-Tab which manages some Settings of a Picker used in the other view.
To my question: I want the picker to reload all components when the Tab changed or the settings in s selectorview changed. How would you solve this?

Thanks,
morymac

Comment: if your issue is solved.. please accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab-Bar based apps handle the tab change event using any of the following delegate methods:

```
 – tabView:shouldSelectTabViewItem:
 – tabView:willSelectTabViewItem:
 – tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:
```

you can call the PickerView refreshing methods in any of the above(preferably the first and second ones). [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTabViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps. For any further help, please add comments

Comment: I know, that this is a Noob-Question (Sorry!), but can I have multiple Delegates in one .m File. My header looks like this: <!-- lang-cpp --!>
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate><!-- lang-none --!>
The Editor tells me, that I there is no NSTabViewDelegate. Did I just take the wrong Name!

Comment: checkout the reference.. it is definitely objective-c

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in Markup (Have to get used to that!!)